# How to import eps to word

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, eps

I'm currently writing my thesis is to involve multiple maps, I thought to save them as .eps (vector image) to reduce the size but still keep high resolution.

So I try to import them as Word version 2013: Insert> Image. Once the .eps image is imported, it appears just a frame inside "can not display the image." I tried to convert pdf but still no image, just an empty frame. I Tried to search but I can not find a solution.

Comment: Answers here might offer some help on your case too http://superuser.com/questions/426405/importing-an-eps-vector-file-to-microsoft-word-without-losing-quality

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert your .eps files into .jpg and than import .jpg into your Word file. 
In order to convert follow the following steps:

How to Convert an EPS File to a JPG in Adobe Illustrator

Step 1: Open your EPS file in Illustrator, then go to File > Export.

Step 2: Name your file and choose where you want to save your JPG. ...

Step 3: Click on the Format bar and choose JPG.

Comment: I don't think it is well assumed that someone writing a thesis in word is going to have adobe illustrator and concurrently did not know adobe illustrator natively works with a vector image.